# Pointer that points to return of function. Initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

I have some trouble with pointers. I have a function that should return the node in a linked list, the function should return the pointer to a variable. I'm confused and cannot see what I do wrong!

data.h - header file

```
int add(int num);
struct message *findMessage(int num);

typedef struct list_el message;
```

data.c - Linked list.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_el {
    int num;

    struct list_el *next;

};

typedef struct list_el message;
struct list_el *head, *tail;



int addNode(struct list_el *curr)
{
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = curr;

    } else {
        tail->next = curr;
    }

    curr->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}

int add(int num)
{
    message *curr;

    head = NULL;

    curr = (message*) malloc(sizeof(message));
    curr->num = num;
    addNode(curr);

    return 0;
}

message *findMessage(int num)
{
    message *curr;

    for(curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        if(curr->num == num) {
            return curr;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Main.c - MAIN

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "data.h"

int main(void)
{
 int num = 2;

 add(num);

 message *curr = findMessage(num);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not actually allocating a new node in add/addNode - you need to call malloc to allocate the storage.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I just coded this in as an example. Its corrected now, but the pointer problem is not fixed yet.

Comment: @user265767: nope - the code as posted above is still broken - you're not allocating any nodes.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `tail->prev = tail;` makes no sense—you are linking the tail node to itself.

Comment: Many simple/obvious bugs still - try stepping through the code in a debugger

Comment: I will later, any proposed debugger? Can someone please point out a solution to the pointer problem?

Comment: @user265767: After making your code compile, I couldn't see a problem with it. The `findMessage` call in `main()` finds the node which was allocated by `add`. One of the bugs I found (don't know whether anybody mentioend this): your `add` function doesn't actually add a node. It always resets the whole list because it rewrites `head`.

Comment: but if I write  printf("num is %d", curr->num); after  message *curr = findMessage(num); I will get the error dereferencing pointer to incompatible type??

Comment: `findMessage()` returns `message *`, `((message *)cur)->num` is `int`, and `printf()`'s `%d` takes `int` -- I see nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not include the definition of `struct list_el` into the header? Otherwise `main` cannot work with it.

Comment: isn't that the same as typedef it like I did?

Comment: @user: No, the header must contain the actual structure declaration. Otherwise any external code would be unable to work with it :-)